# Facebook Android SDK Graph API Version

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbsdk

Yesterday, I got the mail that my app uses features of fb sdk which will not be supported in the newly released graph api v8 from 24th October. One of the feature was :

> A client or app token will now be required for querying user pictures
> through public_profile. Queries without a token will return a generic
> silhouette as the user picture.

Turns out, I was not requesting permission for picture in my login. I only got id from login and used that in url below to get user profile picture:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/%1$s/picture?width=400&amp;height=400
```

As it turns out, it is working completely fine. I still looked at [official docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v8.0/user/picture) where they suggested making a `GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest`. Works fine with that too.

The whole point of my question is that I found no breaking change in my code. It was all working perfectly with both methods. Therefore, I checked both fb-sdk version and graph api version used. They were as following:

```
SDK Version: 5.15.3
Graph Api Version: 5.0
```

As currently, latest is `7.1.0`, I upgraded my fb sdk and printed versions again:

```
SDK Version: 7.1.0
Graph Api Version: 6.0
```

So, I have 2 questions:

1. Why did I get a warning mail regarding update in graph api v8?
2. Why is the latest Graph API version not used in latest Android sdk?

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2):

1. It may be a common warning message for all who are requesting public profile. So, if you are not using then you can simply ignore it.
2. Both SDKs are being release independently. As per Android SDK [changelog](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md?fbclid=IwAR1eC8z5lyTBrv41TgQQOhI9Chytd7GpAJbFBaRj5PdbJ7lv0TCuxSYGbSU), it may not be updated with the latest Graph API version. You can wait for a new version with latest Graph API integrated.

Comment: I have an iOS app for which I received the same email but I verified breaking_changes parameter where everything works fine. I hope this is ignorable.

Comment: @PareshThakor not sure about iOS but as per this changelog, iOS sdk is updated with Graph API 7.0: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md